# How to plot a graph of the values in a column in Pandas DataFrame grouped by a different column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph of all the values in a column, grouped by a different column in descending order (sorted by a third column)

I've created a small example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

groups = list(range(1, 6)) + list(range(20, 25))
groups *= 10

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'score': np.random.rand(100), 'group': groups, 'id': [f'id-{i}' for i in range(100, 200)]})
unique_groups = len(df['group'].unique())
mean_df = df.groupby('group').mean().rename({'score': 'group_avg'}, axis=1)
df = df.merge(mean_df, on='group').sort_values('group_avg')

>>df.head(15)
       score  group      id  group_avg
99  0.221270     24  id-199   0.380676
90  0.116831     24  id-109   0.380676
91  0.317264     24  id-119   0.380676
92  0.164701     24  id-129   0.380676
93  0.638165     24  id-139   0.380676
98  0.813191     24  id-189   0.380676
95  0.360128     24  id-159   0.380676
96  0.740481     24  id-169   0.380676
97  0.215156     24  id-179   0.380676
94  0.219574     24  id-149   0.380676
69  0.084655     21  id-196   0.395563
68  0.173920     21  id-186   0.395563
67  0.271351     21  id-176   0.395563
66  0.809964     21  id-166   0.395563
60  0.031930     21  id-106   0.395563

df.set_index('group').plot(legend=True, marker='v', linestyle='None', markerfacecolor='None', grid=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: The Graph from my code]

The desired output should be in descending order (sorted by group_avg)
and without the gap in the middle.
What I'm trying to achieve is a plot of all the values per group with the average as another dot for each group
Sort of a histogram like, but with data points instead of bars

I've also tried adding the line:

```
df['group'] = df['group'].astype('category')
```

before plotting and received the graph:

[image]

The problem here,is that the X-axis has range of 100 points instead of 10.

Comment: Would a swarmplot (https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) be closer to your expected output?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I actually found something that looks the way I want in seaborn,
[sns.catplot(jitter=False)](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html#categorical-scatterplots)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three options I came up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

groups = list(range(1, 6)) + list(range(20, 25))
groups *= 10

df = pd.DataFrame({'score': np.random.rand(100), 'group': groups, 'id': [f'id-{i}' for i in range(100, 200)]})
df['group'] = df['group'].astype('category')

mean_df = df.groupby('group').mean().rename({'score': 'group_avg'}, axis=1)
df = df.merge(mean_df, on='group').sort_values('group_avg')


def testing():
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    unique_groups = df['group'].unique()
    print(df)

    plt.show()


def first_working():
    unique_groups = df['group'].unique()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.stripplot(x='group', y='score', color='c', size=7, order=unique_groups, jitter=False, data=df, ax=ax,
                       marker='d', alpha=0.8)
    ax = sns.pointplot(x='group', y='group_avg', order=unique_groups, data=df, ax=ax, ci=None, markers='v', size=10,
                       color='orange', alpha=1)
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()


def second_working():
    unique_groups = df['group'].unique()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax = sns.stripplot(x='group', y='score', color='blue', size=5, order=unique_groups, jitter=False, data=df, ax=ax)
    # ax = sns.stripplot(x='group', y='group_avg', marker='v', linestyle='None', size=10,
    #                    color='red', order=unique_groups, jitter=False, data=df, ax=ax)
    sns.pointplot(x='group', y='group_avg', order=unique_groups, data=df, ax=ax, ci=None)
    ax.grid()
    plt.show()


def third_working():
    bars = df['group'].unique()
    mapping_name_to_index = {name: index for index, name in enumerate(bars)}
    df['group'] = df['group'].replace(mapping_name_to_index)
    pos = np.arange(len(bars))
    df.set_index('group').plot(legend=True, marker='v', linestyle='None', markerfacecolor='None', grid=True)
    plt.xticks(pos, bars)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_working()
    second_working()
    third_working()
```